# Fundamental principles of counting

Tags: divisor-counting-function, fundamental-solution

Of all numbers between 10,000 and 99,999, inclusive how many.

A- Do not contain the digit 5?

B- Do contain the digit 5?

C- Are odd and contain no digit more than once?

D- Have no two consecutive digits the same?

I've worked part D, and I got 9^5 would be the answer, but I just want help on A-->C.

Comment: About $A)$ How many numbers $< 10^5$ do not contain the digit 9 ? What about the numbers in base $9$ with $5$ "digits" ?

Comment: 10^5 -9^5 I don't know if I did it correctly.

Comment: A result alone isn't the same as a reasoning.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your attempts on items A - D.  You've asked four questions in one post (not good to do). So, how about you show what you've tried on each, and we can either verify your work, of suggest where you may have erred, and why.

Comment: You wisen up and help a person that needs help. Don't be coming here putting me down. I have a test tomorrow, I'm trying my best doing them. I have 40 problems I only asked 3 questions. Stop being so ungrateful and help someone that needs help so God will bless you and your family who ever you are .

Comment: No, not just three questions, but  at least 8 today. If you look at my profile and answers, I help, and have helped thousands of folks.  It's poor posts that expect and feel entitled to have help at the last minute that steal time from those asking questions on which they've spent a lot of time and effort, and are willing to put time in their questions.  So stop acting like a self-entitled student who feels it's perfectly fine to insist others do your homework.  You are the ungrateful one. I've never been ungrateful to anyone from whom I'm asking help. I hope you learn this.

Comment: So I would show work even if it's wrong, obviously I've worked on them. If I couldn't figured them out. I would just post it. I don't really know you never helped me, you always put me down to be honest

Comment: Zaid  Yes, indeed, show your work/attempts, even if it is unsuccessful, because we can help clear up confusions that may have led to errors.  It also helps us to see what is *right* about what you tried, as well as confusions.  We can all help you much more when we can see what you know, what is correct, vs. where you need a clearer understanding.  Any way, I've engaged with you on only two of your posts, those you posted today.  That is far too soon for either of us to judge one another, don't you think?

Comment: You are correct, I have some questions I don't even feel like posting it anymore, because you would just come and comment on my posts and say show your work even if I show my work, you would comment negatively, but it's ok. I hope you have a great day.

Comment: Zaid, why would you say that?  I'd be delighted if you post a question, along with your work on it, or even simply what you know might apply in answering it, whether it's correct, or incorrect.  It is not fair of you to claim I will comment negatively, whatever you do.

Comment: Alright Sir amWhy.

Comment: I don't think I can post anymore questions. I think I'm locked.

Comment: Have you been given a temporary block, or post limit, as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited)?

Comment: No but I didn't try to post a question to see if I'm blocked.

Comment: Well, keep me posted, if you find yourself unable to post tomorrow. Okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to use the fundamental principle of counting. Since all of these numbers will be between $10,000$ and $99,999$, there are $9$ possible first digits, and $10$ possible digits for each other place value.

Problem A: If none of them contain the number $5$, then there are $8$ possibilities for the first digit and $9$ for the others, for a total of $8*9^4$ numbers.

Problem B: If all of them contain $5$ and there are a total of $90,000$ numbers between $10,000$ and $99,000$ inclusive, the number containing $5$ is $90,000$ minus the number that don't contain $5$, which is $90,000-8*9^4$.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

For A, pick each digit such that it's not a $5$. The leftmost digit is handled differently than the other four.

For B, use the fact that the set of numbers in A and this set are mutually exclusive.

For C, pick an odd rightmost digit. Pick a tens digit that's different (may or may not be odd). Pick a hundreds digit that's different than the other two. And so forth.

Comment: Ya I know that I have to not count any 5 and then for B I have to count how many 5. But how do you do it .

Comment: You got through part D. Do it the same way: multiply.

Comment: What do you multiply?

Comment: Multiply the number of ways you can pick each digit together. For part D, first digit has nine possibilities (one through nine). Second digit needs to be something different, so nine possibilities there. Same with third, fourth, and fifth digits, which gives you the correct answer $9^5$. Use the same reasoning for A and C. For B, subtract the answer in A from the total count of numbers.